# What is the purpose of this string in this simple exercise?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding so I've been doing exercises. This one is about a car that the user commands to start and stop. My question is that why did the given solution include the first line in the following code?:

```
command = ""
started = False
while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("The car has already started")
        else:
            started = True
            print("The car started")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("The car has already stopped")
        else:
            started = False
            print("The car stopped")
    elif command == "quit":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    elif command == "help":
        print("""start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit- quit the game""")
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand")
```

I tried removing the first line and running the code and as far as I could tell it worked perfectly. If I'm missing something obvious I apologize!

Comment: Nope.  Just superstition.  MAYBE they started out saying `while command != 'quit':` instead of the infinite loop.

Comment: no use if this is the whole code, otherwise this object can be used after `while` code block

Comment: Short answer: This is python and you don't need to instantiate a string the way its done on the first line

Comment: @TimRoberts you are correct; they started with while command != "quit" and then removed it to prove it could be simplified. Very impressive that you could deduce that.

Comment: It serves no functional purpose. In fact, if you have Python 3.10+ you don't need it at all as this pattern is well suited to match/case

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see is for readability.
I don't say it's a good practice, just try to guess why it has been done here.

When opening the source code everyone can see which variables will be used by the program and their type.

`started` has to be initialized because it has a initial state.

For `command` it doesn't need to be initialized but it shows that it will be used and that its type is `str`.

Type hints can also be used instead of assigning than assign the empty string.

`command: str` instead of `command = ""`